# CSS Grid grid-column auto feature based on items inside that are wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to push CSS Grid to limits and handle as much as I can without using javascript login. I understand that I will certainly have to use javascript, but I am trying to push the limits.

- The main grey parent has 4 columns (in this example). We use a `repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` for grid column template.
- The ORDER is a customer order that can one or more PRODUCTS
- We want the ORDER to be a default of `grid-column: 1`
- We would also like ORDER to make use of PRODUCTS by extending from `grid-column: 1 / span 2` - `grid-column: 1 / 3` and so on.
- Also, the parent needs to keep track of these when more ORDERs are created.

Here are some example images below to show what I need to happen. Again, I understand javascript might need to be a factor, but I want to push grid as well.

[image]

Here are some example styled components. Orderlanes is a grid that repeats based on minmax width. OrderContainer I was trying to manually set grid-column: 1 / span 3, just to see what happens.

```
export const OrderLanes = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  grid-area: order-lanes;
  grid-column-gap: 2px;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  background-color: lightgray;
`;

export const OrderContainer = styled.div`
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;

  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3; // I WOULD LIKE THIS TO BE AUTO
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
`;

export const Product = styled.div`
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 2px;
`;

export const ProductItem = styled.section`
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 1px;
`;
```

Comment: I get the concept, but if you could provide the code you've tried to create these scenarios, it would make helping you more feasible.

Comment: I am looking for concepts on what is possible with grid. This is less about how to code it and a "can css grid do this". I added some code, but my way of coding is not so important. The question is about what is grid capable of.

Comment: I would actually use flexbox for this

Comment: Actually nvm tried it with flexbox but your product containers wouldn't all line up the way you want, maybe look into using subgrid. Kevin Powell has some good videos on the topic